# bottom navigation view and navigation drawer at the same time

Tags: java, xml, android-studio, navigation-drawer, bottomnavigationview

Quite simply, the first option in the navigation drawer, that I currently have functioning with fragments, I want that first open to open up my view with the bottom navigation items which has its own fragments. I know i'm going about this all wrong but any assistance would be helpful. I also want to keep the action bar at the top whilst I'm in my bottom navigation view activity or fragment if I can transform it, I clearly don't know much.

```
Navigation Drawer Activity
```

```java
public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    private DrawerLayout drawer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.main_nav_view);

        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.main_fragment_container, new AccountFragment()).commit();
            navigationView.setCheckedItem(R.id.nav_account);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.nav_account:
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.main_fragment_container, new AccountFragment()).commit();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_nfc:
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.main_fragment_container, new NfcFragment()).commit();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_report:
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.main_fragment_container, new ReportUserFragment()).commit();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_settings:
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.main_fragment_container, new SettingsFragment()).commit();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_about:
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.main_fragment_container, new AboutFragment()).commit();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_help:
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.main_fragment_container, new HelpFragment()).commit();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_logout:
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.main_fragment_container, new LogoutFragment()).commit();
                break;
        }

        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();

        }

    }
}
```

```
Navigation Drawer XML
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:openDrawer="start">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/darkgrey"
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            android:elevation="4dp"/>

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/main_fragment_container"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:id="@+id/main_nav_view"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu"/>

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

```
Bottom Navigation View Activity
```

```java
public class BottomNavigation extends AppCompatActivity implements BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_bottom_navigation);
        BottomNavigationView navView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        loadFragment(new PeopleFragment());
    }

    private boolean loadFragment(Fragment fragment) {

        if(fragment != null) {

            getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment)
                    .commit();
           return true;
        }
return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {

        Fragment fragment = null;

        switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {

            case R.id.navigation_people:
                fragment = new PeopleFragment();
                break;

            case R.id.navigation_products:
                fragment = new ProductsFragment();
                break;

            case R.id.navigation_scanner:
                fragment = new ScannerFragment();
                break;

            /*case R.id.navigation_nfc:
                fragment = new NfcFragment();
                break;*/

            case R.id.navigation_collection:
                fragment = new CollectionFragment();
                break;

            case R.id.navigation_profile:
                fragment = new ProfileFragment();
                break;

        }
        return loadFragment(fragment);
    }
}
```

```
Bottom Navigation View XML
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    tools:context=".BottomNavigation">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="56dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"></FrameLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/darkgrey"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/grey"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/grey"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

I do that, with this code in my `onCreate`

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private AppBarConfiguration mAppBarConfiguration;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


        FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_perfil, R.id.nav_carrito, R.id.nav_pedidos, R.id.nav_soporte, R.id.nav_articulos)
                .setDrawerLayout(drawer)
                .build();
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);

       //al dar click sobre las opciones del menu de navegacion inferior entra aqui
        BottomNavigationView  btnMenu=(BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.bottomNavigationView);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(btnMenu, navController);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, mAppBarConfiguration)
                || super.onSupportNavigateUp();
    }
}
```